# The Royal Affair

Tags: crosswords

This is a Normal Crossword. For the final answer, you will need to give me something that completes the "pattern". The pattern is for you to find out. And finally, I have given you the grid but no numbering(Can't make everything easy for you fellas). 
[image]

**Across:**
Archaic British term meaning vulgar(7)
Jaw-dropping emotion(3)
Archaic term for declares or interprets(8)
Harry Potter’s friend Weasley(3)
Unnecessary honking leads to this(4,4)
Moves from one place to another(4)
Long ago(4)
Monarch’s Play partly written by Shakespeare(6)(P.S. I am looking only for the name)
Descent towards the earth(5)
German for me or myself(3)
Predecessors of Primary Oocytes(7)
Dances seen in 19th Century France(7)
Scottish word for Self(3)
Oblong block of gold or silver(5)
Dark lava rock(6)
A magical influence(4)
One of the Five Great Lakes of North America(4)
Pienta who acted in 7 Chinese Brothers(8)
Operate an equipment(3)
Woolen fabrics(8)
Psychedelic drug(3)
King’s law?(7)

**Down:**
Forcefully move or push(5)
Extending a contract(8)
Football player Edwin Van der __(3)
Town in South London, England(7)
Type of mineral, known as Trona(4)
Bulls get angry on seeing this(6)
Screen behind the Altar(9)
Sacred mountain in Crete(3)
You pull this when you trick someone(3)
Sawyer(7)
Formula one racer who died in San Marino(5)
Malignant tumors in connective tissues(9)
_____ Bandit(3,5)
King’s actor Hurt(7)
“One of Us” singer Joan ____(7)
Kind of apple juice(5)
Someone who makes amends for past mistakes(6)
Greek hero who was killed by Achilles(5)
A hundred thousand(3)
An old English letter(3)
Second minor Prophet of Ancient Israel(4)
Like a tricky road curve(3)

Hint:

> SKOG is very close but they have missed an alternative interpretation of the title.

Hint 2(potentially big):

> You need to relate the title to a recent event.

Comment: It looks to me like the order the clues are presented would match standard crossword numbering if it were present on the puzzle. Is this accurate?

Comment: Though if that were the case, the Minor prophet clue should be before the "a hundred thousand" clue for consistency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might have found the connection to the title:

> As SKOG mentioned, EDWARD, WILLIAM, and CHARLES are all members of British royalty.
>
>  "Royal Affair" refers to the recent royal wedding, featuring Prince Harry.
>
>  Therefore, the pattern is completed by HARRY.
>
>  EDIT: ManyPinkHats found that the four most recent [royal weddings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_royal_weddings#United_Kingdom) correspond to the four names earlier, in crossword order. This provides evidence for the pattern.

Comment: Even more concretely, [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_royal_weddings#United_Kingdom) shows that the four most recent events relate to exactly the three in the grid (in Across-then-Down order, like the clues) and the fourth you give as your answer.

Comment: If you incorporate MPH' s suggestion, I will accept this answer

Answer (score 3):

Got the grid mostly completed.

> Clues are in regular crossword order as noted by Ian MacDonald
>  [image: Nearly completed grid]

As to the "pattern":

> Three of the clues have the word "King" or "Monarch" in them, which ties to the title "The Royal Affair".
>  They give the names EDWARD, CHARLES and WILLIAM, which are certainly the names of royalty without their numbers. As noted by another solver (MadJaqk), if we think of this as British royalty, the last King Edward was Edward VIII, the last William was William IV, and the last Charles was Charles II.

So the answer might be:

> A monarch whose name only shows up once, like Victoria or Anne.

It's possible we've missed something though.

Comment: I think you're just missing E and S, in that order

Comment: This is close. But, you have missed something. I will let you ponder a bit longer.

Comment: @hagfy Thanks for the spot. I'll update the image.

Comment: E and C are children of [QE2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elizabeth_II), and W is her grandson.  Not sure if that's relevant, though.

Comment: For some more nudge, try to think of meanings of "Affair".